# DropDownList population in JavaScript using datasource from Oracle

Tags: javascript, html, oracle

I have a function to add rows in a table using `innerHTML`:

```js
function addRowToTable(tblParam) { 

  var tbl =document.getElementById(tblParam); 
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;    
  var cnt = lastRow; var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  document.form_sample_1.cnt_rltv.value = cnt; 

cellLeft.innerHTML = "<td><select class=form-control input-xsmall name=rltv" + cnt +   " id=rltv" + cnt + "><option value='' selected=selected>&nbsp;</option><option value='Father'>Father</option>
<option> value='Mother'>Mother</option><option> value='Brother'>Brother</option>
<option>value='Sister'>Sister</option></select></td>"
}
```

How can I put select option data source from a database?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting a giant string of HTML, create the DOM nodes and hook them up to each other.

```
var dbResults = ["Mother", "Brother", "Sister"];
var select = document.createElement("select"); 

for (var i=0; i < dbResults.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerText = dbResults[i];
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Then append the `select` node to whichever parent you want.

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.append(select);
```

Comment: This is good advice, but I suspect the first line is really the crucial bit, since the OP seems to be confused about where to get the database results and how to get them from the server to the client.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but just like @NathanTuggy mentioned it above, i still have a problem showing the select query results to dropdownlist option.